# Prove $18080108080 \sum_{k=0}^{1560-1} 10^{10k}+1$ is prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I saw this fact on twitter:

[image]

I would like to know how one would show this number is prime. Is there an elementary way to show that this number is prime? Is there a simplified primality testing algorithm in this case that possibly I could code and run on my computer? Is there a reference to a paper that can be given?

Comment: It could have passed a probable prime test.

Comment: @AndreNicolas, I'd be interested in something bring me up to speed with, for instance, the Miller Rabin test. I forget it.

Comment: Rabin test is by now far from state of the art probabilistic test. There is a huge literature. Your number is very special, and at size the "probability" of primality are getting small, but not ridiculously small.

Comment: author http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_A._Pickover probably originally from one of his books. The pattern is sufficiently special that a special-purpose test may prove it prime. I'm guessing you can ask questions on Twitter, ask the original source.

Comment: It's not clear to me that it's a "special-purpose" prime at all. If we choose $a,b,c,d,e\in\{0,1,8\}$ and consider the numbers written $(1abcdedcba)^n1$, then from the prime number theorem we should expect about a 3% chance that one of them with $1000<n<2000$ is prime. It doesn't seem to be remarkable that there is _some_ of the $3^5=243$ combinations of $a,b,c,d,e$ where one of them is prime, for no particular reason (and it would probably be easy to find another one by a brute-force search on computer).

Comment: Consider the fact that something like this could be posted on twitter without anyone actually verifying whether or not it is true. This is the code I ran, feel free to see if there are any mistakes.$\quad$
 `s = ""; PrimeQ[
 10*ToExpression[Do[s = StringJoin["1808010808", s], {1560}]] + 1]`

Comment: @Brad Something like:
PrimeQ[Sum[10^(10*k), {k, 0, 1560 - 1}]*1808010808*10 + 1]; is better. Your code returns PrimeQ[1+10*null]
.

Comment: I think the issue is with the `Do[]` statement. I prefer the concatenating string method because it works faster than a summation. Consider running the `Do[]` statement outside of `ToExpression[]`.

Comment: The first mention of this I've seen is March 2012, so it isn't new.  Simple probable prime tests run pretty fast at this size, taking less than a minute to show it is a BPSW, Frobenius, and multiple random-base M-R probable prime.  This is pretty convincing.  The real trick would be to run it through proof software, e.g. Primo, then upload the certificate to factordb.com.  On a modern computer that would probably take about a month of computation.

Comment: Some discussion on verifying the primality of this number can be found in [this blog post](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2013/01/17/narcissus-prime-in-python/) and its comments.

Comment: @ChrisPhan, those are all probable primality tests, and most are pretty bad (Python/SymPy and Perl6 both use the first <n> prime bases, where <n> is quite large, hence the time taken).  Mathematica does BPSW + an extra M-R with base 3 which is the best of the bunch by far.  User Charlie does a simple Fermat test then incorrectly claims it to be deterministic.

Answer (score 2):

Maple's probabilistic primality test "isprime" returns true for this number. Here's the Maple code:

> p:=18080108080*add(10^(10*k),k=0..1560-1) +1:
>   isprime(p);